# How do I check if a record exist?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an appointment model and I want to validate if a record with the same date and hour exist.

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :adate, :atime, :doctor_id  
  validates :adate, :presence => true     
  belongs_to :doctor
  validates_date :adate, :after => lambda { Date.current }  

  validate :appointment_uniqueness

  def appointment_uniqueness
      # if date (:adate) and hour(:atime) exists then
      # date is not available
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validates :adate, :uniqueness => { :scope => :atime }
```

see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness

Comment: Can I scope to fields?

validates :adate, :uniqueness => { :scope => :atime, :day }

Comment: validates :adate, :uniqueness => { :scope => [:atime, :day] }

Comment: I posted this question yesterday maybe you could help with it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430143/how-to-organize-data-fields-within-a-html-table