# How to organize data fields within a HTML table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I'm building a view to manage two models, `Doctor` and `Schedule`.

I want to create a `html` table to hold these fields. each column(day) should hold the eight hours so it can be user friendly.

Example:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Sunday   !   Monday   !   Tuesday   !   Wednesday   !   Thursday   !   Friday   !   ...   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    hour1       hour1        hour1         hour1           hour1          hour1
    hour2       hour2        hour2         hour2           hour2          hour2
    ...         ...          ...           ...             ...            ...
    hour8       hour8        hour8         hour8           hour8          hour8
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

_form

```
<% @rows_per_column = 18 %>
<% @columns = 7 %>

<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th>Sunday</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    </tr>
    <% 0.upto(@rows_per_column).each do |row| %>
      <tr>
    <%= f.fields_for :schedules do |builder| %>     
        <% 0.upto(@columns - 1).each do |column| %>
        <% index = row + (column * @rows_per_column) %>
        <td><%= index %>


        <div class="field">
    <%= builder.label :day %>
    </div>


    </td>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My idea is to assign a default value through an array to each day and and each hour, the table `Schedule` has a is_available column to set the doctor hour availability (a boolean).

I've been trying to tackle this with a nested loop but I can not get it to work right. Any idea on how could I achieve this?